# How to find all Mapbox layers in DeckGL?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, use-ref

I'm following [this](https://deck.gl/gallery/mapbox-layer) example that puts Mapbox labels on top of a layer. This seems to be written using the plain Mapbox package. I'm hoping to do the same for a map component in DeckGL.

The relevant code from the example:

```
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: document.body,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      center: [-122.4, 37.79],
      zoom: 15,
      pitch: 60
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
      const firstLabelLayerId = map.getStyle().layers.find(layer => layer.type === 'symbol').id;
```

My code using DeckGL is:

```
      <DeckGL
        initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
        layers={layers}
        onClick={expandTooltip}
        onViewStateChange={hideTooltip}
        onWebGLInitialized={onInitialized}
        views={MAP_VIEW}
        controller={{
          touchRotate: true,
          inertia: 600,
        }}
      >
        <StaticMap
          reuseMaps
          mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
          preventStyleDiffing={true}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        />
      </DeckGL>
```

How can I access `getStyle().layers` in the above components? I tried using `useRef`, as in this simplified component:

```
const mapRef = useRef();
<DeckGL
        {...viewport}
        maxZoom={20}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        ref={mapRef}
      >
```

but found that it doesn't contain information about the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wait until `mapLoad`s, something like:

1 - Define a new `ref`:

```
const mapRef = useRef();
```

2 - Wait for map loads:

```
<StaticMap
  ref={mapRef}
  onLoad={onMapLoad}
  ...otherProps
/>
```

3 - Use `getMap` method. Now we are sure that Mapbox instance exists:

```
const onMapLoad = useCallback(() => {
  const map = mapRef.current.getMap();
  const mapboxLayers = map.getStyle().layers;
  console.log(mapboxLayers);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `deckg`l layer after map gets loaded into the browser. For that purpose, you can use:

`Map.on('load', callback function)`

For more reference use this https://youtu.be/x6UcMcAWNMo